# How to create a flow to move folders in Microsoft Flow

Tags: power-automate

I'd like to create a flow, run once a day, to move everything from one folder to another. (I'm using the personal 1 TB OneDrive).

I didn't find a step to move folders (files only).

Is it possible to create a flow to move folders?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Power Automate, it is not possible without 3rd party connectors. 3rd party connectors has cost component to it. So it is upto you to use them or not. You can [check this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Create-copy-move-and-remove-SharePoint-folders-cross-site-with/ba-p/102500) to achieve what you want through Plumsail connector.

If you want to do this for personal work, i would suggest to simply use your current approach and copy all files one-by-one to new folder in `OneDrive`.

However, remember that `OneDrive` connector doesn't have any `Action` to create a folder, but if you can provide new folder name before your file name, it will create it for you before moving the file. [Check this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-folder-in-OneDrive/td-p/318736) to understand how it works.